# Embedded Google Calendar changing the default time format

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is it possible to change the default time format of embedded Google Calendar from 12-hour (am/pm) to the 24-hour (military time) format? I found no way how to change it in settings of the calendar or in settings of the embedding, the only thing I found out is to how to change the time format for me as a logged user. But once I logout and visit the page again, the times are again in the am/pm format.

Comment: How and where exactly are you embedding the calendar? Which page are you visiting? Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: @iansedano Hi, I'm not sure how much can I share the code publicly because not all of the code is my work and it is also for someone else. However, I'm embedding the calendar in my site using the iframe tag, which is generated by default in Google Calendar "Settings and sharing" under "Integrate calendar". It can be customized, but I already tried that and found no option which would enforce 24 military for all non-logged (in Google account) users. I digged a bit more and I think it is not actually possible at the moment.

Comment: If its not possible maybe file a feature request? https://issuetracker.google.com/ - Also, why not answer your own question with the fact that it's not possible and ideally a link to a feature request for it? I can't seem to find any feature requests for that at the moment.

Comment: @iansedano Last time I did that, it turned out it actually was possible so I'm now very careful to not spread false conviction. :D However I will put a request for a feature, that is a good idea. If it is indeed not possible, I should learn it from the request feature reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted Google through the issue tracker and the request was evaluated and forwarded forward so maybe in the future it might be possible. For now, it's not.